# Clearing or resetting a singleton in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm writing a test method to reset the value of a singleton variable, however I have no clue how to do it. please can someone assist me with the test code to test the following:

```
public class Service extends CompositeService {

  .....
//SINGLETON
private static Service singleton;

public static Service get() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Service ();
    }
    return singleton;
}

private Service () {}
....
...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your test class needs to "interfere" with `private` variables that are not accessible through your class's public API, you should add the `@TestVisible` annotation:

```
@TestVisible
private static Service singleton;
```

Your unit test can then do

```
Service.singleton = null;
```

when needed.

It's broadly preferable, where possible, to test using the public API, as this insulates your test class from the implementation details of your class and makes it run tests like any other consumer of the class's API. However, there are lots of situations, as it sounds like you've discovered, where it does become necessary to reach into the private state of a class during a test.